# Adding html to a ui web view at runtime in code, based on a switch

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, text

Is it possible for me to add text to a uiwebview and change the text and colours in this view without having separate html files? So I define whats in the html file in a switch statement? I do this at the moment using labels, but I can't have more than one colour in a label so I need to use html, as core text looks quite complicated.

```
switch (counter)
{
    case 0:
        titleLabel.text = @"needs to be more than one colour";
      break;
    case 1:
        titleLabel.text = @"needs to be more than one colour";
        break;
```

and so on...

Can I in some way define whats in a html file in  tags in the code in these switches rather than having seperate html files? If so how would I do this?

Cheers,

Lewis

Comment: I'd like to introduce you to Javascript :).  Actually I wouldn't because it is a pain but that is the only route to interacting with your HTML content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your HTML contains a CSS class called myCssClass where you specify your colors, and a label:

```
<label id="myTextElement">A Label</label>
```

You can programmatically execute javascript to set a different CSS class using code like this:

```
UIWebView *webView; 
.
.
.
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"myTextElement\").className = \"myCssClass\";"];
```

though honestly if you watch the WWDC 2012 videos on CoreText you might be less intimidated...

Comment: I've downloaded the video, having a watch now, thanks. Is it not possible for me to define the whole html file in obj-c rather than having a physical html file?

Comment: You can set the content of the webview directly from a string, [UIWebView loadHTMLString:baseURL:].  You'll need inline CSS styles.  You can then interact with the content via javascript