# Can a UIButton be used to perform a hyperlink click in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uibutton

This is perhaps a crazy question but I am looking to use a UIButton in an iOS app and when you click on it, it will in turn click a hyperlink on a webpage loaded in a hidden UIWebView.

The link can also be triggered by a javascript call I am just not sure if it's possible from a UIButton to a UIWebView?

Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call javascript inside your UIWebView from your UIButton click handler, directly calling your javascript function that handles the href click.

See [Adding html to a ui web view at runtime in code, based on a switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478460/adding-html-to-a-ui-web-view-at-runtime-in-code-based-on-a-switch/12478702#12478702)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest just using an HTML form with a submit button instead.  I've done this and it's much simpler.  Something like:

```
    - (NSString *)makeSubmitForm
    {
        NSMutableString *ms = [NSMutableString string];

        [ms appendString:@"<p><form action=\"formentry\">"];
        [ms appendString:@"<input style=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" />"];
        [ms appendString:@"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"fieldtype\" value=\"submit\" />"];
        [ms appendString:@"</form>"];

        return ms;
    }
```

and then just look for it in your UIWebViewDelegate.  The code below does that and also checks for other form entry stuff if it exists (like a text field input)

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
    {
        NSString *surl = [[request URL] absoluteString];

        NSRange ner = [surl rangeOfString:@"formentry?"];

        if (ner.location != NSNotFound){
            NSString *argstr = [surl substringFromIndex:ner.location+ner.length];
            NSMutableDictionary *md = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            NSArray *args = [argstr componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
            for (int i=0; i < args.count; i++){
                NSString *keyval = [args objectAtIndex:i];
                NSArray *pair = [keyval componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
                [md setObject:[pair objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[pair objectAtIndex:0]];
            }
            [MyDelegate tellItWhatever:md];
        } 

         return NO;
    }
```